# D3 javascript color from JSON attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

Using D3 Javascript and JSON, I need to create something very similar to:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

The JSON file (copied from website) looks something like:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
```

Now instead of the "size" in the code above, I have "score" (i.e. "score": 3).

What I want to achieve is the diagram similar to the website, but the difference is that is the score is over a certain threshold (e.g >5), I want the small blue circle to be of a certain color (i.e. red).

I know this needs to be updated in the index.html file, but I just don't know how to get around to doing that. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do this is to slightly modify the code that appends the `circle`s. You need to change the snippet

```
node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5);
```

to

```
node.append("circle")
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.score > 5 ? "red" : "steelblue"; })
  .attr("r", 4.5);
```

You can obviously apply something like this to e.g. the fill colour in the same way. If you have a larger number of different colours and thresholds, it might be worth investigating using a [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Scales) instead of a conditional statement.

Comment: Thanks sooo much Lars much. One problem is that, I don't actually want an extra node at the end of my diagram with the colour. Is it possible to colour the previous node instead based on the scores?

Comment: This wouldn't add an extra node, it would colour the one with the respective score. Do you mean that the score of a node determines the colour of the following node?

Answer (score 0):

Change your JSON like so:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "score": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "score": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "score": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "score": 743}
     ]
    },
```

Now use a function to check for the condition in the data and set the style for the circle:

```
node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill",function(d){
          return ((d.score > 5)?"red":"blue");
      });
```

Comment: Thanks so much. One problem is that, I don't actually want an extra node at the end of my diagram with the colour. Is it possible to colour the previous node instead based on the scores?